# If $x:[0,\infty]\to E^\ast$ is a function into a topological space and $x^\ast([0,\zeta))⊆E$, how can we characterize the left-limit at $\zeta$?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let

- $(E^\ast,\tau^\ast)$ be a topological space and $$\mathcal N_{\tau^\ast}(x^\ast):=\left\{N^\ast\subseteq E^\ast:N^\ast\text{ is a neighborhood of }x^\ast\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }x^\ast\in E^\ast;$$
- $E\in\tau^\ast$ and $\tau:=\left.\tau^\ast\right|_E$;
- $x^\ast:[0,\infty]\to E^\ast$;
- $\zeta\in[0,\infty]$ with $x^\ast([0,\zeta))\subseteq E$.

> Are we able to show that
>
> 1. If $t\in(0,\zeta)$, then $x^\ast$ has a left-limit at $t$ iff $$\exists\ell\in E:\forall N\in\mathcal N_\tau(\ell):\exists\delta\in(0,t]:x^\ast((t-\delta,t))\subseteq N?\tag1$$
> 2. If $x^\ast$ has left-limits in $[0,\zeta)$, then $x^\ast$ has a left-limit at $\zeta$?

Regarding 1: Assume $x^\ast$ has a left-limit at $t$. Then there is a $\ell\in E^\ast$ such that $$\forall N^\ast\in\mathcal N_{\tau^\ast}(\ell):\exists\delta\in(0,t]:x^\ast((t-\delta,t))\subseteq N^\ast\tag2.$$ But how do we show that $\ell\in E$?

In order for $t$ to exist, we must clearly have $\zeta\in(0,\infty]$ and hence can assume that. Then there is a $u\in(t,\zeta)$ and, by definition of $\zeta$, $$x^\ast([0,u])\subseteq E\tag3.$$ Intuitively, it should be impossible that the left-limit at $t<u$ is in $E^\ast\setminus E$, but how can we prove this rigorously?

(If necessary, assume that $x^\ast$ is right-continuous on $[0,\zeta)$.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $E^\ast=\Bbb R$, $x^\ast(t)=t-\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $E=(-\infty,1)$, $\zeta=2$, $t=1$. Then $x^*([0,\zeta))\subset E$, left limit of $X^\ast$ exists and is equal to $1$ but $1\notin E$.

Observe that $x^*$ is right-continuous.

Consider now $x^*(t)=\sin(1/(2-t))$ for $t\neq 2$, $x^*(2)=0$. Then $x^∗$ has left limits in $[0,\zeta)$ but hasn't a left limit at $\zeta$.